Upgrading vertx-hazelcast to 4.5.11 causes thread block upon identifying hazelcast instance uuid
After upgrading from Vert.x 4.2.8 to Vert.x 4.5.11, which uses Hazelcast 5.3.5, we have observed a significant increase in idle CPU utilization (from around 10% to 60%) and frequent Thread blocked exceptions in our application. The specific error is triggered during Hazelcast MapProxyImpl.entrySet() queries, resulting in the following stack trace:
 2024-11-15 11:52:44,139 354652 [vertx-blocked-thread-checker] WARN  i.v.core.impl.BlockedThreadChecker - Thread Thread[vert.x-eventloop-thread-2,5,main] has been blocked for 10139 ms, time limit is 2000 ms 
io.vertx.core.VertxException: Thread blocked
    at java.base/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:371)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.AbstractInvocationFuture.manageParking(AbstractInvocationFuture.java:694)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.AbstractInvocationFuture.get(AbstractInvocationFuture.java:616)
    at com.hazelcast.map.impl.query.QueryEngineImpl.addResultsOfPredicate(QueryEngineImpl.java:215)
    at 
com.hazelcast.map.impl.query.QueryEngineImpl.doRunOnQueryThreads(QueryEngineImpl.java:166)
    at com.hazelcast.map.impl.query.QueryEngineImpl.runOnGivenPartitions(QueryEngineImpl.java:142)
    at com.hazelcast.map.impl.query.QueryEngineImpl.execute(QueryEngineImpl.java:109)
    at com.hazelcast.map.impl.proxy.MapProxySupport.executeQueryInternal(MapProxySupport.java:1441)
    at com.hazelcast.map.impl.proxy.MapProxySupport.executeQueryInternal(MapProxySupport.java:1405)
    at com.hazelcast.map.impl.proxy.MapProxyImpl.executePredicate(MapProxyImpl.java:801)
    at com.hazelcast.map.impl.proxy.MapProxyImpl.entrySet(MapProxyImpl.java:750)
    at com.hazelcast.map.impl.proxy.MapProxyImpl.entrySet(MapProxyImpl.java:744)
    at com.trimble.tcp.events.retriever.service.hzc.HazelcastService.getWorkerInstanceUuid(HazelcastService.java:58)

Previous configuration: Vert.x 4.5.3 (Hazelcast 4.2.8).
Current configuration: Vert.x 4.5.11 (Hazelcast 5.3.5).
Using Vert.x dependencies: vertx-web-client, vertx-core, vertx-web, vertx-hazelcast, vertx-micrometer-metrics, vertx-mysql-client.

When I cross verified with vertx-hazelcast 4.5.11 but excluding hazecast(5.3.5) and forcing to use hazelcast 4.2.8 in my project , i was not facing any issues . What would be the appropriate way to migrate to hazelcast 5.3.5 with vertx upgarde .
